# Why Transfer-Encoding:Chunked sent instead of Content-Encoding:gzip for some of clients?

Tags: http, gzip, content-encoding, transfer-encoding

I confused. I have two laptops that connect to internet via same modem device. For web servers that enabled `gzip` in them for example `microsoft.com`, One of my Systems(64-bit) get response header with `Transfer-Encoding:chunked`. The other get response header in correct form with `Content-Encoding:gzip`. Why?
Both Systems have Windows 7 SP1(one of them 32-bit and the other 64-bit). I tested with same version of Chrome on both Systems. I also test with FireFox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Transfer Encoding chunked content length that going to be transfered is not needed.the data is broken as pieces and sent over the network.

From [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding):

> Chunked transfer encoding is a data transfer mechanism in version 1.1
>   of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) in which data is sent in a
>   series of "chunks". It uses the Transfer-Encoding HTTP header in place
>   of the Content-Length header, which the earlier version of the
>   protocol would otherwise require. Because the Content-Length header
>   is not used, the sender does not need to know the length of the
>   content before it starts transmitting a response to the receiver.
>   Senders can begin transmitting dynamically-generated content before
>   knowing the total size of that content.
>
> The size of each chunk is sent right before the chunk itself so that
>   the receiver can tell when it has finished receiving data for that
>   chunk. The data transfer is terminated by a final chunk of length
>   zero.
>
> ***Encoded data***
>
> In the following example, every second line is the start of a new chunk, with the chunk size as a hexadecimal number
>   followed by \r\n as a line separator.

```
4\r\n
Wiki\r\n
5\r\n
pedia\r\n
e\r\n
 in\r\n\r\nchunks.\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

> Note: the chunk size indicates the size of only the chunk data. This
>   does not include the trailing CRLF ("\r\n") at the end of the counted
>   characters. In this particular example, the CRLF following "in" is
>   counted 2 toward the chunk length of 0xE (14), and the CRLF in its own
>   line is also counted 2 toward the chunk length of 0xE (14). The period
>   character at the end of "chunks" is the 14th character, so it is the
>   last character of the chunk of length 0xE (14). The CRLF following the
>   period is the trailing CRLF, so it is not counted toward the chunk
>   length of 0xE (14).
>
> ***Decoded data***

```
Wikipedia in

chunks.
```

Comment: Although [not illegal or forbidden](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/would-it-be-ok-to-paste-content-from-wikipedia-into-a-popular-empty-tag-wiki) I don't think it's a good idea to write an answer that's 95% verbatim copy of Wikipedia...

Comment: any way it gives solution na it would be better la

Comment: The actual solution is your first sentence, the next 100 lines are just an explanation of what chunked transfer is, unfortunately as an unedited wad of text copypasted from wikipedia.

Comment: if you use Content-Encoding:gzip in client side you have to use Accept-Encoding:gzip in your httprequest.